# Javascript - How to pull data from Google Firebase randomly?

Tags: javascript, random

I'd like all my Firebase content to load randomly every time you refresh, but I can't seem to get all my Firebase data into a dictionary where I can randomize them.

I have a global array and I'm trying to push my files in there and then iterate through them. But Javascript thinks the array is empty because the timing is off.

```
var randomStore = new Array;

function homeSetup() {
    if(ref.toString() == featuredRef.toString()){
        addFeaturedImages();
    }
    console.log('randomStore length is ' + randomStore.length);
}

function addFeaturedImages(){
    featuredRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        var doc = {
            // 'name': snapshot.key, //name is the id
            'artist': snapshot.val().artist,
            'author': snapshot.val().author,
            'projectTitle': snapshot.val().projectTitle,
            'text': snapshot.val().text
        };
        randomStore.push(doc);
        console.log('randomStore length HERE is ' + randomStore.length);
    });
}
```

Considering how the code is typed, I would assume that the 'randomStore length HERE is' log would be typed first, but instead I get this:

```
randomStore length is 0
randomStore length HERE is 1
randomStore length HERE is 2
randomStore length HERE is 3
```

If I got my data into a different array, then I could manipulate it to sort randomly and stuff like that, but I can't seem to get it in there properly.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the timing is off? What did you mean by that ?

Have you heard of Javascript Promise's ?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

This post explains promises very good. Read this very carefully, because if you are working with firebase, you will be using promises on **daily**!

Comment: You don't need to call `addFeaturedImages();` Just leave the on as is, without the addFeaturedImages

Comment: IvRRimUm, doesn't make a difference. I have that function because I have more groups, and it's fine. 

What are javascript Promise's? I would assume that the console.log inside the 'ref.on' function would be printed first, but it's printed AFTER. So I would assume that because it's Firebase, it's running asynchronously, so the console.log inside homeSetup is executed before the looped ones.

Comment: Yep, Promises are made right exactly for that. I will update the post with quote from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `featuredRef.on("child_added")` use `featuredRef.once('value')`. This should get you the whole array at once. Attach a `then` listener where you continue with the work of `homeSetup`.

```
function homeSetup() {
    var cb = function(randomStore) {
        console.log('randomStore length is ' + randomStore.length);
        //....
    };


    if(ref.toString() == featuredRef.toString()){
        addFeaturedImages(cb);
    } /* else if(...) {
        addFooImages(cb)
    }*/ 
}


function addFeaturedImages(cb){
    featuredRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
         //TODO: transform elements of the array?
         cb(snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Code untested, but I should get you started.